How using OleDb to get sheet names in sheet order from Excel?
I can't get sheel names in sheet order from Excel using OleDB.
I was find topic below from 15 eyars ago but it was a bust back when.
Using Excel OleDb to get sheet names IN SHEET ORDER
Maybe someone already find the solution.
Dim d As DataTable
Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(constring)

con.Open()
d = con.GetSchema("Tables")
'd = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, New Object() {Nothing, Nothing, Nothing, "TABLE"})         con.Close()

my code is working but table names sorted by alphabet and not in order of Excel sheets

I suspect that you can't do it using ADO.NET. The tables in a database don't really have an order so, if you treat your workbook as a database, the sheets are probably not considered to have an order either. You would probably have to use DAO, Office Interop or OpenXML.

If you're open to using ClosedXML, the documentation at Moving worksheets shows it as having a .Position property for a .Worksheet. Ah, now I've seen the "API" section at the bottom of the navigation: Int32 Position "Gets or sets the position of the sheet."

This question is similar to: Using Excel OleDb to get sheet names IN SHEET ORDER. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

... look at this undervoted answer, it explains how to extract the sheet names from the internal XML documentation without needing Interop.
